# Filter two table rows by using group by with join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, group-by

I have two tables as Sales and SalesDocument.

**Sales Table**

```
RequestId(PrimaryKey)   ReqType   DateTime
---------               -------   --------
    1                    Buy      22/10/2015
    2                    Buy      03/11/2015
    3                    Sell     10/11/2015
    4                    Return   11/12/2015
    6                    Sell     11/12/2015
    7                    Buy      20/12/2015
```

**Sales Document Table**

```
RequestId(Ref.Key(FK))   ReqDocument  ReqDocURL
---------                -----------  ---------
   2                     Doc1       Http://..Doc1.PDF
   3                     Doc2       Http://..Doc2.PDF
   3                     Doc3       Http://..Doc3.PDF
   4                     Doc1       Http://..Doc1.PDF
   4                     Doc2       Http://..Doc2.PDF
   4                     Doc3       Http://..Doc3.PDF
   6                     Doc2       Http://..Doc2.PDF
   6                     Doc3       Http://..Doc3.PDF
```

Now I need to select the records in both tables by using RequestId(as Ref.Key) and the condition are,

1)In 1st Table,Need to get distinct ReqType(FirstColumn:*RequestType*) and It's count(SecondColumn:*RequestTypeCount*) based between two date ranges.

2)In 2nd Table, Need to calculate total no.of requested documents(ThirdColumn:*SumOfReqDocument*) by using RequestType(RequestType is not in 2nd table, hence we need to map with 1st table(sales) by RequestId and get the sum of documents.

The output should be,

```
RequestType     RequestTypeCount     SumOfReqDocument
-----------     ----------------     ----------------
 Buy                 3                   1
 Sell                2                   4
 Return              1                   3
```

I tried some SQL query but it does not result the actual result. Please help me on this SQL query\Suggest me some other query.

My Query is,

```
 SELECT ReqType as RequestType,count(ReqType) as RequestTypeCount,count(salesDoc.DocumentURL) as SumOfReqDocument FROM Sales sales inner join SalesDocument salesDoc on
sales.RequestId=salesDoc.RequestId where sales.EndDate >= '2015-10-22 10:34:09.000' AND sales.EndDate <= '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
group by sales.ReqType
```

Comment: `it does not show the actual results` what does it show then ?

Comment: Actually it is returning some wrong result like it returns total no.of docs for both the columns. My query is wrong. I dont know where i am doing the mistake. If you have any other solution\query for this result, Please advise.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is changing your Inner Join  to a Left Outer Join so that you can pick up ReqTypes that have no docs associated with them for the given time period.

Comment: @Love2Learn: I used Left Outer join, it is returning the actual result. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, and `COUNT DISTINCT ReqestID`  for RequestTypeCount

```
SELECT ReqType as RequestType
    ,count(DISTINCT sales.RequestId) as RequestTypeCount
    ,count(salesDoc.ReqDocURL) as SumOfReqDocument 
FROM Sales sales 
LEFT JOIN SalesDocument salesDoc 
  ON sales.RequestId=salesDoc.RequestId 
WHERE sales.EndDate >= '2015-10-21 10:34:09.000' AND sales.EndDate <= '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000'
group by sales.ReqType
```